# Android uploading profile picture for a Firebase authenticated user

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to add an image to the Firebase storage, where each user can upload his profile picture from his files or camera, and it should be stored in his own folder that has his uid as name. I have the following code, however pressing on the ImageView doesn't do anything:

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

    CircleImageView profileImage;
    TextView email;

    public StorageReference storageRef;
    FirebaseStorage storage;


    public static ProfileFragment newInstance() {
        ProfileFragment profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
        return profileFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

        profileImage = view.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
        email = view.findViewById(R.id.email);

        String user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail();
        email.setText(user);

        storageRef = storage.getReference();

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        final String userUid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        final Uri contentURI = data.getData();

        profileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(contentURI != null) {

                    StorageReference childRef = storageRef.child("/images/"+ userUid +".jpg");

                    UploadTask uploadTask = childRef.putFile(contentURI);
                    uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Upload successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Upload Failed" + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Select an image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

From what I've read, onActivityResult doesn't work with fragments, however I can't think or find any topics of how it should be done to work. Could somebody please help me with making this work, and also, how do I fetch the profile picture of each user after I've uploaded it? I'm using the built in Firebase Authentication system with Email, Google and Facebook authentication, and I'm trying to make it work without storing users additionally in the database.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this below snippet :

Step 1:- Add the firebase storage dependency in build.gradle (Module:app)file. Latest Dependency for firebase storage is:

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.0'
```

Step 2:-Setting up the activity_main.xml layout file

Step 3:-Setting up the MainActivity.java file

```
FirebaseStorage  storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance(); 
StorageReference  storageReference = storage.getReference();

        private void uploadImage() 
        { 
            if (filePath != null) { 

                // Code for showing progressDialog while uploading 
                ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this); 
                progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading..."); 
                progressDialog.show(); 

                // Defining the child of storageReference 
                StorageReferenceref=storageReference.child("images/"+UUID.randomUUID().toString(); 

                // adding listeners on upload 
                // or failure of image 
                ref.putFile(filePath) 
                    .addOnSuccessListener( 
                        new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() { 

                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess( 
                                UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) 
                            { 

                                // Image uploaded successfully 
                                // Dismiss dialog 
                                progressDialog.dismiss(); 
                                Toast 
                                    .makeText(MainActivity.this, 
                                              "Image Uploaded!!", 
                                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) 
                                    .show(); 
                            } 
                        }) 

                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() { 
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) 
                        { 

                            // Error, Image not uploaded 
                            progressDialog.dismiss(); 
                            Toast 
                                .makeText(MainActivity.this, 
                                          "Failed " + e.getMessage(), 
                                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) 
                                .show(); 
                        } 
                    }) 
                    .addOnProgressListener( 
                        new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() { 

                            // Progress Listener for loading 
                            // percentage on the dialog box 
                            @Override
                            public void onProgress( 
                                UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) 
                            { 
                                double progress 
                                    = (100.0
                                       * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() 
                                       / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount()); 
                                progressDialog.setMessage( 
                                    "Uploaded "
                                    + (int)progress + "%"); 
                            } 
                        }); 
            } 
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for read my guide.I think you have pass wrong context please pass the current fragment context so that call current fragment onActivityResult() method.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand you. You are refering to this guide: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/image-upload-to-firebase-in-android-application--cms-29934